# laravel 4 - two routes on same controller function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I want to do something I don't know if it is feasible.

here's my routes.php

```
Route::get('mockups/user/skills/{skill}', 'MockupsController@user');
Route::get('mockups/user/tours/{tour}', 'MockupsController@user');
Route::get('mockups/user', 'MockupsController@user');
```

and my MockupsController@user function

```
public function user($skill=null,$tour=null){
    if($tour ==null && $skill != null)
        return View::make('demo/mockups/user/public',array('skill'=>$skill));
    if($tour!=null && $skill ==null)
        return View::make('demo/mockups/user/public',array('tour'=>$tour));
    return View::make('demo/mockups/user/public');

}
```

if I get the `/mockups/user/tours/tour1` url, the controller calls the `demo/mockups/user/public` view without sending the `$tour` variable. how to make it works?

**EDIT**

```
public function user($skill=null,$tour=null){
    echo var_dump($skill);
    echo var_dump($tour);
    die();
    if($tour ==null && $skill != null)
        return View::make('demo/mockups/user/public',array('skill'=>$skill));
    if($tour!=null && $skill ==null)
        return View::make('demo/mockups/user/public',array('tour'=>$tour));
    return View::make('demo/mockups/user/public');

}
```

displays

```
string(5) "tour1" NULL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont understand why you are making it so complicated. Why not just do

```
Route::get('mockups/user/skills/{skill}', 'MockupsController@skills');
Route::get('mockups/user/tours/{tour}', 'MockupsController@tours');
Route::get('mockups/user', 'MockupsController@user');

public function skills($skill)
{
    return View::make('demo/mockups/user/public',array('skill'=>$skill));
}

public function tours($tour)
{
    return View::make('demo/mockups/user/public',array('tour'=>$tour));
}

public function user()
{
    return View::make('demo/mockups/user/public');
}
```

Comment: call it whatever you want - tourlist(), usertours() - the point is you should separate the logic into 3 controller functions.